# My Navigation Keys and Status Bar are lost!

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5

I'm using Nexus 5, Lollipop 5.0.1 (rooted), no custom ROM, and Franco Kernel. I was changing my Nav Keys by an app. By mistake, I hit restore and then after the reboot I found that my nav bars are gone and even the status bar!

Now I literally have to reboot to switch in apps. Please help!

Comment: Which app did you use?

Comment: Dirty flash Lollipop over itself, meaning don't wipe anything. All your data will be intact. If your using Xposed framework, it will have to be re-enabled. If necessary you can wipe cache.